# getting IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE is undefined error while trying to create listbox c++

Tags: c++, listbox, visual-studio-2013

I've wanted to create such simple multiple selection allowed listbox and to do that, I've done the following: BTW I'm using visual studio 2013 ultimate

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Strsafe.h"
#include "Afxres.h"


typedef struct 
{ 
    TCHAR achName[MAX_PATH]; 
    TCHAR achPosition[12]; 
    int nGamesPlayed; 
    int nGoalsScored; 
} Player; 

Player Roster[] = 
{ 
    {TEXT("Haas, Jonathan"), TEXT("Midfield"), 18, 4 }, 
    {TEXT("Pai, Jyothi"), TEXT("Forward"), 36, 12 }, 
    {TEXT("Hanif, Kerim"), TEXT("Back"), 26, 0 }, 
    {TEXT("Anderberg, Michael"), TEXT("Back"), 24, 2 }, 
    {TEXT("Jelitto, Jacek"), TEXT("Midfield"), 26, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Raposo, Rui"), TEXT("Back"), 24, 3}, 
    {TEXT("Joseph, Brad"), TEXT("Forward"), 13, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Bouchard, Thomas"), TEXT("Forward"), 28, 5 }, 
    {TEXT("Salmre, Ivo "), TEXT("Midfield"), 27, 7 }, 
    {TEXT("Camp, David"), TEXT("Midfield"), 22, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Kohl, Franz"), TEXT("Goalkeeper"), 17, 0 }, 
}; 


INT_PTR CALLBACK ListBoxExampleProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, 
        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            // Add items to list. 
            HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE);  
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(Roster); i++) 
            { 
                int pos = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, 
                    (LPARAM) Roster[i].achName); 
                // Set the array index of the player as item data.
                // This enables us to retrieve the item from the array
                // even after the items are sorted by the list box.
                SendMessage(hwndList, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM) i); 
            } 
            // Set input focus to the list box.
            SetFocus(hwndList); 
            return TRUE;               
        } 

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return TRUE;

        case IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE:
            {
                switch (HIWORD(wParam)) 
                { 
                case LBN_SELCHANGE:
                    {
                        HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE); 

                        // Get selected index.
                        int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0); 

                        // Get item data.
                        int i = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETITEMDATA, lbItem, 0);

                        // Do something with the data from Roster[i]
                        TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
                        StringCbPrintf (buff, ARRAYSIZE(buff),  
                            TEXT("Position: %s\nGames played: %d\nGoals: %d"), 
                            Roster[i].achPosition, Roster[i].nGamesPlayed, 
                            Roster[i].nGoalsScored);

                        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_STATISTICS, buff); 
                        return TRUE; 
                    } 
                }
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Altough I've included everything I need I get the following errors:

```
Error:identifer "IDC_LISTBOX_EXAMPLE" is undefined.
```

Why I'm getting such an error ? Is there anyone to help me ?

**EDIT**

I'm not using MFC template , do I have to ?

Comment: Go to your dialog (resources), right click on your listbox control -> Properties. And tell your ID value

Comment: The resource Files ( In the right solution explorer) is empty.Is it wrong ?This is the first time that I've tried to implement some GUI, so If it is a foolish question sorry about that @user2451677

Comment: `#include "resource.h"` That constant has to be *somewhere*. Find it (its likely in the file mentioned). Make sure you're using it in your .rc script, and the identifier is properly defined.

Comment: Do you have DialogProc() call somewhere ?

Comment: not yet, other than I've posted here I've only empty main function  @user2451677

Comment: @WhozCraig altough I've include resoruce.h too, problem still continues

Comment: @user2451677 if you have enough time could you share complete example about creating listbox ? it doesnt have to be with the same as I've created I just want to learn steps.

Comment: @newbornToCS, ok, I will try

Comment: @user2451677 I'm so greatful, waiting for it.

Comment: The *that* resource.h file isn't being included in your resource .rc script. One way or another *both* the .c code and the .rc script need that identifier, from the same place (a resource.h like file) if at all possible (and it always is possible).

Comment: @user2451677 ccould you do it ?

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry but I did not understand what you're trying to explain ? Could you understand what should I do more simpler ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so, you have nothing, except dialog procedure. Ok.
File -> New... -> Project:
[image]
Then Ok -> Next. You need to create dialog based application. For this, create empty application:
[image]
and click Finish.

Now you have empty project. You need to add dialog resource.
Right click on project -> Add -> Resource. And then Dialog -> New:
[image]
You will have empty dialog. Right click on them -> Properties. Remember the value of ID (IDD_DIALOG1 in my case):
[image]
Then you need to add list box control. Go to ToolBox window (View -> Toolbox, Ctrl+Alt+X), select ListBox and drag&drop to dialog:
[image]
OK. Then you need to know the ID of your list box (the same as for dialog: Right click on list box control -> Properties -> ID). It's IDC_LIST2 in my case.
For your example you need to add in the same way Static Text Control (In the same way as with list box: Toolbox -> Static Text -> drag& drop to dialog form). Give another ID for this static control (Right click -> Properties -> Id -> Change to IDC_STATISTICS):
[image]

THATS ALL YOU NEED TO DO WITH YOUR DIALOG :)

And now - the code. Add new cpp file to the project:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include "resource.h"

INT_PTR CALLBACK ListBoxExampleProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, 
        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int CALLBACK _tWinMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_  LPTSTR lpCmdLine,
  _In_  int nCmdShow)
{
    ::DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, ListBoxExampleProc);
    return 0;
}

typedef struct 
{ 
    TCHAR achName[MAX_PATH]; 
    TCHAR achPosition[12]; 
    int nGamesPlayed; 
    int nGoalsScored; 
} Player; 

Player Roster[] = 
{ 
    {TEXT("Haas, Jonathan"), TEXT("Midfield"), 18, 4 }, 
    {TEXT("Pai, Jyothi"), TEXT("Forward"), 36, 12 }, 
    {TEXT("Hanif, Kerim"), TEXT("Back"), 26, 0 }, 
    {TEXT("Anderberg, Michael"), TEXT("Back"), 24, 2 }, 
    {TEXT("Jelitto, Jacek"), TEXT("Midfield"), 26, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Raposo, Rui"), TEXT("Back"), 24, 3}, 
    {TEXT("Joseph, Brad"), TEXT("Forward"), 13, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Bouchard, Thomas"), TEXT("Forward"), 28, 5 }, 
    {TEXT("Salmre, Ivo "), TEXT("Midfield"), 27, 7 }, 
    {TEXT("Camp, David"), TEXT("Midfield"), 22, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Kohl, Franz"), TEXT("Goalkeeper"), 17, 0 }, 
}; 


INT_PTR CALLBACK ListBoxExampleProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, 
        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            // Add items to list. 
            HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST2);  
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(Roster); i++) 
            { 
                int pos = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, 
                    (LPARAM) Roster[i].achName); 
                // Set the array index of the player as item data.
                // This enables us to retrieve the item from the array
                // even after the items are sorted by the list box.
                SendMessage(hwndList, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM) i); 
            } 
            // Set input focus to the list box.
            SetFocus(hwndList); 
            return TRUE;               
        } 

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return TRUE;

        case IDC_LIST2:
            {
                switch (HIWORD(wParam)) 
                { 
                case LBN_SELCHANGE:
                    {
                        HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST2); 

                        // Get selected index.
                        int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0); 

                        // Get item data.
                        int i = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETITEMDATA, lbItem, 0);

                        // Do something with the data from Roster[i]
                        TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
                        StringCbPrintf (buff, ARRAYSIZE(buff),  
                            TEXT("Position: %s\nGames played: %d\nGoals: %d"), 
                            Roster[i].achPosition, Roster[i].nGamesPlayed, 
                            Roster[i].nGoalsScored);

                        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_STATISTICS, buff); 
                        return TRUE; 
                    } 
                }
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Compile and run! And remember - **never** use WInAPI (or MFC, no matter) for writing UI. **Use Qt**!

And the scrren of your app:
[image]

Comment: really amazing answer I wish I can accepts as an answer twice.